# Use Blender exporting .h file (IOS)

Tags: iphone, ios

I download a file from https://github.com/jlamarche/iOS-OpenGLES-Stuff but I can't exporting .h file.Because the latest blender version is 2.6.4 ,the python script latest version is 2.6.2. How do I do?